# SSMS - Execution Plan Operators - Est/Act Rows Display

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-execution-plan

I've noticed that some SQL Server execution plans display the estimated and actual number of rows as part of the operator info and others don't (requiring hovering and the popup to get it).  Is this a version thing in SSMS or is it a setting somewhere that I can tweak?  I am using SSMS v17.9.1 (gotta have the debugger) and I don't see anything obvious in Tools > Options.  Thanks.

Comment: Random note that you may not be aware of: Estimated rows is per Execution, whereas Actual is the total. To compare, you need to multiply the two Estimated figures together

Comment: Semi-unrelated question, if anyone happens to notice this..  Is the 'Query cost (relative to the batch)' value always based on estimated data or does it update (in the Actual Execution Plan) after the batch is run to reflect the actual results of the query execution?

Comment: Always estimated, that's another gotcha. And take Missing Index hints with a large pinch of salt. You may want to look at [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer)

Comment: Thanks CF.  And yep on the Missing Index suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need SSMS v18.x to show both number.

Get it here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

[image]

Comment: That's not what he was looking for. If that's your *estimated plan*you can hover over the operators to see the *estimated" number of rows only. If  it's the "actual" plan then you get the estimated and actual number of rows..

Comment: Actually, that *was* what I was looking for (Is this a version thing in SSMS..).  And as it sounds like the choice, version feature-wise, is between going without the integrated debugger or going without the default-displayed row counts on the operators, I'll be keeping the debugger.  Thanks ML.

Answer (score 0):

***Display** estimated execution plan* returns the execution plan that SQL Server expects to touch. Here, only the *estimated* number of rows is returned because the actual number of rows are unknown.

***Include** actual execution plan* returns the *actual* execution plan which includes both the estimated number of rows and actual number of rows touched.

The *estimated* plan is for development and troubleshooting purposes; the actual plan is for analysis.

[image]